# How can I get an ELO Touch Screen to work?

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, touch-screen

I have bought a new touchscreen POS machine and I have installed fedora 14 on it. I couldn't make the touch screen work, as the ELO touch manufacturers have drivers only for kernel 2.6.14 versions. Even though Fedora 14 has precompiled kernel-level driver support for ELO touch screens, I am unable to get it working.

I have tried the `xorg.conf` configuration as well, but nothing is working.

```
Section "Files"  
        FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"  
        FontPath        "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc"  
        FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"  
        FontPath        "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/cyrillic"  
        FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"  
        FontPath        "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/:unscaled"  
        FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"  
        FontPath        "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/:unscaled"  
        FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"  
        FontPath        "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1"  
        FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"  
        FontPath        "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi"  
        FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"  
        FontPath        "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi"  
#path to defoma fonts  
FontPath        "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"  
 EndSection  
 Section "Module"  
 Load    "i2c"  
 Load    "bitmap"  
 Load    "ddc"  
 Load    "dri"  
 Load      "extmod"  
 Load    "freetype"  
 Load    "glx"  
 Load    "int10"  
 Load    "vbe"  
  EndSection  

Section "InputDevice"  
Identifier      "Generic Keyboard"  
Driver          "kbd"  
Option          "CoreKeyboard"  
Option          "XkbRules"      "xorg"  
Option          "XkbModel"      "pc104"  
Option          "XkbLayout"     "us"  
EndSection  

Section "InputDevice"  
Identifier      "Configured Mouse"  
Driver          "mouse"  
Option          "CorePointer"  
Option          "Device"                  "/dev/input/mice"  
Option          "Protocol"              "ImPS/2"  
Option          "Emulate3Buttons"       "true"  
EndSection  

Section "InputDevice"  
Identifier "ELO touchscreen"  
Driver "elographics"  
Option "Device" "/dev/ttyS0"  
Option  "MinX" "375"  
Option  "MaxX" "3700"  
Option  "MinY" "500"  
Option  "MaxY" "3590"  
Option  "UntouchDelay"  "10"  
Option  "ReportDelay"   "10"  
Option  "SendCoreEvents"        "yes"  
Option  "ScreenNumber"  "0"  
Option  "ButtonNumber"  "1"  
EndSection  

Section "Device"  
Identifier      "Intel"  
Driver          "intel"  
BusID           "PCI:0:2:0"  
EndSection

Section "Monitor"  
Identifier      "LCD Touch"  
Option          "DPMS"  
EndSection  

Section "Screen"  
Identifier      "Default Screen"  
Device          "ATI Technologies Inc ATI Default Card"  
Monitor         "ELO Touch"   

        DefaultDepth    24  
        SubSection "Display"  
        Depth           1  
        Modes "800x600"  
        EndSubSection  
        SubSection "Display"  
Depth           4  
Modes           "800x600" "720x400" "640x480"  
EndSubSection  
SubSection "Display"  
Depth           8  
Modes           "800x600" "720x400" "640x480"  
EndSubSection  
SubSection "Display"  
Depth           15  
Modes           "800x600" "720x400" "640x480"  
EndSubSection  
SubSection "Display"  
Depth           16  
Modes           "800x600" "720x400" "640x480"  
EndSubSection  
SubSection "Display"  
Depth           24  
Modes           "800x600" "720x400" "640x480"  
EndSubSection  
EndSection  

Section "ServerLayout"  
Identifier      "Default Layout"  
Screen          "Default Screen"  
InputDevice     "Generic Keyboard"  
InputDevice     "Configured Mouse"  
InputDevice     "ELO touchscreen" "SendCoreEvents"  
EndSection  

Section "DRI"  
Mode    0666  
EndSection
```

Comment: @Deepak, can you post the xorg.conf that you tried, and any error messages you're getting?

Comment: actually I don't know to configure xorg.conf file. Can you tell me how to configure xorg.conf file in fedora 14. by the way how do i find if the hardware is properly connected ? Is there a way to check that..

Comment: @mattdm: I have posted it. I didnt get any error. There is no response though..

Comment: You might want to consider posting the contents of your /var/log/Xorg.0.log as well, because that's what is needed to determine whether it is failing to see /dev/ttyS0 as an elographics device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The X Input Device maintainer for Fedora & X.Org upstream has posted [a guide to Elographics touch screen setup on Linux](http://who-t.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/elographics-touchscreen-setup.html).